# Из истории письма

Tags: языкознание

В каком веке появились пробелы между словами в русском языке? Существует версия, что с созданием печатного станка. Так ли это?

Answer (score 2):

До конца XV века текст пи­сался  без промежутков между словами.
Раньше всех была введена точка (в XV веке), затем — запятая (в XVI веке). После них появилась точка с запятой, которая употреблялась и как знак вопроса, и как промежу­точный знак между двоеточием и запятой.
С возникновением книгопечатания появилась необхо­димость упорядочить знаки препинания. В книгах XVI ве­ка уже использовались запятая, точка с запятой, вопроси­тельный знак (чуть позднее появился и восклицательный знак).
К концу XVIII века стали известны тире, кавычки и много­точие.

Answer (score 2):

Во всяком случае - не раньше. "Апостол" (1564 г.), по тогдашним правилам экономии бумаги ещё был напечатан без пробелов, правда там уже использовались пунктуацианные знаки в их современном понимании. А первой книгой, напечатанной с пробелами, была "Грамматика" Смотрицкого(1619 г.).